# Should I reuse a failed PayPal payment if the user checks out again?

Tags: .net, paypal

I'm integrating PayPal with the [PayPal SDK 1.4.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal/). If a user bails half way through the PayPal payment journey and then checks out again, should I recover the original payment using `PayPal.Api.Payment.Get(apiContext, payPalOrderNumber)`? If I recover it, should I mark the original Transaction as failed and start a new one or reuse the original transaction?

Are these cases documented in the developer guide?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there's nothing wrong with re-using the same `payment` resource if the user checks out again after previously cancelling.  However, the token used for the redirect approval is only good for 3 hours; so unless you know they're checking out again in a short amount of time, it may be better to simply create a new `payment` resource for them to approve.

As far as a place where these cases are documented, your best bet is either the [PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/) site or contacting [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/) directly with your question.